# can somebody figure out what is wrong in this? I am getting linking error

Tags: c++, extern

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern int i;
int main()
{

   i=10;
 cout<<"the value of i is"<<i<<endl;



}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the error.

Answer (score 6):

'extern' tells the compiler that i is defined in another compilation unit.  It will not create storage for it but look for it at link time, when you get the error.  So either link with a module that has i defined or remove the 'extern' qualifier.

Comment: You don't define it in main, you use it in main.
And even if you would define a variable i in main, it would be 2 totally different i's.  The "extern int i" can only refer to i as a global variable.

Comment: No, you are just assigning i with 10, definition says what is i , is it an int or float

Comment: @yesraaj: as long as we're nit-picking: that would _the declaration_ rather than the definition. In fact, `extern int i;` _declares i as an int_ just fine, without defining the actual variable. (Hint: definition tells the compiler/linker to physically allocate space for the variable, which was (previously) declared with a particular type)